# D8 override core class

Tags: drupal-8

I am using [SHS](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module. What I want to do is, override the SHS widget such that the I can alter the query used to fetch the data in the widget. Till now, I have overriden the route controller and have found that the underlying query is being generated from the `loadTree()` function of the  `core/modules/taxonomy/src/TermStorage.php` file.

Now what basically I want is, to override this function, such that I may be able to alter the query to my requirement. Im not sure what is the correct way to do that in OOPS.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [this line](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/shs/tree/src/Controller/ShsController.php#n52)? If so *and* you've already overridden the route by creating your own copy of this controller, you should be able to add your own query here that returns an array of `\Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface` objects per the [function documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21TermStorage.php/function/TermStorage%3A%3AloadTree/8.5.x).

To answer your question of whether or not you can override `\Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage::loadTree()`, I am not aware of a way to do a simple swap and even if there was, being able to override a core function like that would likely cause instability somewhere else in the system. It sounds like you are on the right track by overriding the route controller. To be clear, the steps needed to fully override that controller so it's able to be used by the SHS (or any) module is:

1. Create a custom route by duplicating the route you wish to override and changing the name, controller, and the first slug in the path (and anything else you want, but make sure the route parameters are the same!)
2. Create a custom controller by duplicating the route controller you wish to override. Make sure it matches the controller in your custom route.
3. Use a [form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.5.x) or a [widget_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/8.5.x) to modify the route callback in the relevant element.

At that point you can modify your custom route controller (including the queries) to return anything you want.

EDIT:

Here is a code example of how you could do this using a custom module called `my_module`. In this example, I'm simply modifying the query to return terms of vid `my_vocabulary` with name `Term Name`, but the point here is that you can modify that to be any query you want. Just as a disclaimer, I did not test this code, but I have similarly structured code running on my own site.

my_module.routing.yml

```
my_module.term_data:
  path: '/my-module-term-data/{identifier}/{bundle}/{entity_id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyModuleShsController::getTermData'
    _title: 'Get term data'
    entity_id: null
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

my_module.module

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_field_widget_options_shs_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $element['#shs']['baseUrl'] = 'my-module-term-data';
}
```

src/Controller/myModuleShsController.php

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;
use Drupal\shs\Cache\ShsCacheableJsonResponse;
use Drupal\shs\Cache\ShsTermCacheDependency;

/**
 * Controller for getting taxonomy terms.
 */
class MyModuleShsController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Load term data.
   *
   * @param string $identifier
   *   Name of field to load the data for.
   * @param string $bundle
   *   Bundle (vocabulary) identifier to limit the return list to a specific
   *   bundle.
   * @param integer $entity_id
   *   Id of parent term to load all children for. Defaults to 0.
   *
   * @return CacheableJsonResponse
   *   Cacheable Json response.
   */
  public function getTermData($identifier, $bundle, $entity_id = 0) {
    $context = [
      'identifier' => $identifier,
      'bundle' => $bundle,
      'parent' => $entity_id,
    ];
    $response = new ShsCacheableJsonResponse($context);

    $cache_tags = [];
    $result = [];

    $langcode_current = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();
    $entity_manager = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity.manager');
    $storage = $entity_manager->getStorage('taxonomy_term');

    $translation_enabled = FALSE;
    if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('content_translation')) {
      /** @var \Drupal\content_translation\ContentTranslationManagerInterface $translation_manager */
      $translation_manager = \Drupal::service('content_translation.manager');
      // If translation is enabled for the vocabulary, we need to load the full
      // term objects to get the translation for the current language.
      $translation_enabled = $translation_manager->isEnabled('taxonomy_term', $bundle);
    }
    // CUSTOM CODE STARTS HERE.
    $terms = $storage->loadByProperties(['vid' => 'my_vocabulary', 'name' => 'Term Name']);
    // CUSTOM CODE ENDS HERE.

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $langcode = $langcode_current;
      if ($translation_enabled && $term->hasTranslation($langcode)) {
        $term = $term->getTranslation($langcode);
      }
      else {
        $langcode = $term->default_langcode;
      }

      $tid = $translation_enabled ? $term->id() : $term->tid;
      $result[] = (object) [
        'tid' => $tid,
        'name' => $translation_enabled ? $term->getName() : $term->name,
        'description__value' => $translation_enabled ? $term->getDescription() : $term->description__value,
        'langcode' => $langcode,
        'hasChildren' => shs_term_has_children($tid),
      ];
      $cache_tags[] = sprintf('taxonomy_term:%d', $tid);
    }

    $response->addCacheableDependency(new ShsTermCacheDependency($cache_tags));
    $response->setData($result, TRUE);

    return $response;
  }

}
```

Comment: You are right, I am referring to that line. However, can you specify a bit more on your last line, as to how you can modify the custom route controller. Cause, if you have checked the `getTermData` function, you will notice it returns an object of `\Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface` which has been used in later part of the function to build the return JSON response. Are you suggesting that i dont call the `loadTree` function at all, and instead write my custom query in the controller itself?

Also, regarding your point #3, can you kindly put an example how to do this?

Comment: Thanks to you for taking the time out to put it in code. However, the `loadByProperties` function that you have called doesnt really return a `\Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface` type of object. As a result all the remaining part of the `getTermData` function does not work.

Comment: `Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage::loadByProperties()` returns `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface[]` which should be interchangeable with `TermInterface`. Disclaimer: this was just an example and I did not actually check to see if it would execute.

In any case, I just threw that in as an example - you should be able to modify that with whatever query you want!